# Email headers: Allowed/disallowed characters in FROM header: (display) name

Tags: unicode, utf-8, email-headers, rfc822, rfc2822

I'm trying to find an answer to the question about which characters is allowed (or disallowed) in the
FROM header (display) name..

```
"My Display Name" <my-email@address.com>
```

I'm talking about the **My Display Name** in quotations.

I've looked at [tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) and [tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) but can't seem to find anything specifying these requirements. Perhaps because it accepts all unicode/UTF-8 characters but it doesn't state that either.

Any help or reference to some documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Characters that have values between 33 and 126, inclusive, **except colon**.

So if your "customer" has this name "Clinic: X" this will be blocked by most email client providers. You can "replace the ":" with " " in that case for example.

See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.2

> According to Section 2.2 of RFC 5322 : "A field name MUST be composed
> of printable US-ASCII characters (i.e., characters that have values
> between 33 and 126, inclusive), **except colon**. A field body may be
> composed of printable US-ASCII characters as well as the space (SP,
> ASCII value 32) and horizontal tab (HTAB, ASCII value 9) characters
> (together known as the white space characters)

Answer (score -2):

Email header fields, of which `From` is one, can only contain ASCII characters. See Section 3.1.1 of [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822). However, [RFC 1342](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342) gives a mechanism to work around this limitation.

Comment: RFCs 5322 and 6532 are current.

Comment: RFC 5322 allows only ASCII characters, per [Section 2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.2): "*A field name MUST be composed of printable US-ASCII characters (i.e., characters that have values between 33 and 126, inclusive), except colon.  A field body may be composed of printable US-ASCII characters as well as the space (SP, ASCII value 32) and horizontal tab (HTAB, ASCII value 9) characters (together known as the white space characters, WSP).*" RFC 6532 lifts the ASCII restriction, but only on field bodies, by allowing direct use of UTF-8 without having to use things like MIME.